# What exactly is the $\in$-Induction Principle?

Tags: induction, ordinals

Throughout the post $\mathcal{L}_\text{ZF}$ is the language of $\text{ZF}$, while $\text{fld}(R)$ is the field of the relation $R$, and $\text{wf}(R)$ means the relation $R$ is well-founded i.e.

1. $\forall x\in\text{fld}(R)\exists y\left(x\in y\land R^{-1}[y]\subseteq y\right)$, and
2. $\forall x\subseteq\text{fld}\left(x\neq 0\implies \exists y\in x\forall z\in x\left(\sim z R y\right)\right).$

---

I do not understand the meaning of **Remark 1.3.3** c), which is an application of **Theorem 1.3.2**, in  Holz's *Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic*:

> **Theorem 1.3.2 (Transfinite Induction Principle)**
> If $R$ is well-founded and if $\phi$ is a formula of $\mathcal{L}_\text{ZF}$, then
> $$\text{ZF} \vdash \text{wf}(R)\land \forall x\in\text{fld}(R)\Big(\big[\forall y\in\widehat{x}\ \phi(y)\big]\implies \phi(x)\Big) \implies \forall x\in\text{fld}(R)\ \phi(x).$$

> **Remark 1.3.3** *Important special cases of Theorem 1.3.2 are:*
> $$[\ldots]$$
> $$
> \text{c) $R = \in$: From the axiom of regularity and Lemma $1.3.8$ (see below) we can conclude that the relation $\in$ is well-founded. Thus we can use in ZF the
> so-called }\in\textbf{-Induction Principle:}
> $$
> $$
> \text{ZF}\vdash\forall x
> \Big(\big[\forall y < x\ \phi(y)\big]\implies \phi(x)\Big) \implies 
> \forall x\ \phi(x).
> $$

---

As the $\in$**-Induction Principle** is a special case of **Theorem $1.3.2$** we have that $R$ must be a relation, and $\in$ by itself is not (right?). Some options are $R=\in\cap(\text{ON}\times\text{ON})$ or $R=\in\cap(A\times A)$ for some arbitrary set $A$. If it is the latter, the principle could be restated as

**Result:** given any set $A$, and any formula $\phi(x)$, we have that
$$
\text{ZF}\vdash\forall x\in A
\Big(\big[\forall y\in A \text{ such that } y \in x\ \phi(y)\big]\implies \phi(x)\Big) \implies 
\forall x\in A\phi(x).
$$

So, What *exactly* is the statement of the $\in$**-Induction Principle**? What is $R$?

Comment: Why bring in $A$? The statement makes sense as a statement about any formula $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Personally I would stick in another set of parentheses to clarify it: $\forall x ((\forall y < x\ \phi(y)) \implies \phi(x)) \implies 
\forall x\phi(x)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I edited the post so as to be clearer in what I fail to understand regarding the $\in$-Induction Principle. I also explain why I think $A$, or _something_, needs to be brought: to make $R$ a relation.

Answer (score 2):

$\in$-induction is written exactly as stated. However, you are **correct** that it is not literally an instance of TIP since $\in$ is "too large" to be a relation. There are two ways to think about the relation between TIP and $\in$-induction:

- **Sweep details under the rug and "schematize" TIP**. For each pair of formulas $\varphi, \psi$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "If $\varphi$ defines a well-founded class-relation and $\psi$ defines a subclass of the field of $\varphi$ then $\psi$ has a $\varphi$-minimal element." This is a "theorem scheme," and taking $\varphi(x,y)\equiv x\in y$ yields TIP.
- **Don't treat it as a literal instance**. While $\in$ itself is not a relation, $\in\upharpoonright V_\alpha$ is for every ordinal $\alpha$. And thinking about how TIP applies to the $\in\upharpoonright V_\alpha$s will give a quick proof of $\in$-induction.

Generally this sort of detail is often ignored in natural-language expositions, but you are right that - technically - $\in$-induction is not a genuine instance of TIP as written.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand now. Is $V_\alpha$ the $\alpha$ level in the von Neumann hierarchy?

Comment: @Sam Yup, that's exactly right. Basically, a failure of induction would be "locally witnessed."

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  The book under discussion uses 'class relation' in your first category as the definition of relation, so the TIP in Theorem 1.3.2 is the schematized TIP, which covers $\in$-induction.  Even though the OP doesn't bother to tell us that - I can tell because axiom 1. of 'well-founded relation' actually says that the transitive closure of $R$ is set-like.  Being set-like is a separate issue than 'well-founded', and it is *never* necessary to assume a set-relation is 'set-like'.  It always is.  Only for a 'class relation' is that extra assumption necessary.